# The frontend receives an array as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, ejs

I am building a website with JavaScript, express.js, ejs and Node.js and i just ran into a problem.

I am sending an array to the frontend this way:

```js
const dataToSend = [
  {
    id: "ID",
    name: "Name"
  },
  {
    id: "ID",
    name: "Name"
  }
]

res.render('configure', {
    array: dataToSend
});
```

And getting it on the frontend with ejs this way:

```
<%= array %>
```

If i print the array on the frontend the result will be `[object Object]` and I also printed out `typeof('<%= array %>')` which returned string.

I found some topics about this but i coun't find anything that helps.
I would like to know what is the proper way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @cmgchess Oh, interesting. `dataToSend.toString()` returns  `'[object Object],[object Object]'`. TIL

Comment: `<%- JSON.stringify(dataToSend )..` gives array object as it is

Comment: https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/ a very nice site

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. It seems we must also `JSON.stringify` the array in addition to using the `<%- %>` tags. `<%- JSON.stringify(dataToSend) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the array is being converted to a string. In JavaScript, objects (`{...}`) have a `toString` method that returns the string `[object Object]` by default.

To solve this, you need to ensure that the array isn't being converted to a string.

In EJS, you have a variety of tags to choose from:

```
Tags
<% 'Scriptlet' tag, for control-flow, no output
<%_ ‘Whitespace Slurping’ Scriptlet tag, strips all whitespace before it
<%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
<%# Comment tag, no execution, no output
<%% Outputs a literal '<%'
%> Plain ending tag
-%> Trim-mode ('newline slurp') tag, trims following newline
_%> ‘Whitespace Slurping’ ending tag, removes all whitespace after it
```

source: https://ejs.co/

You're likely looking for this: `<%-` to output the `JSON.stringify`'d array.

```
<%- JSON.stringify(array) %>
```

Comment: Oh i didn't know about that documentation. Thank you it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the array in script? If yes you would get that as a string. Try this instead:
Outside the script tag stringify the JSON and assign it to a variable like this:-

```
<% let theArray = JSON.stringify(array) %>
```

Then in the script tag, JSON.parse the ejs local variable theArray to a variable.
Like this:-

```
<script>
let arrayFromEjs = JSON.parse("<%- theArray %>");
</script>
```